# Does JBOSS 5.1 run in JDK 1.4?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, jdk1.4

Does JBOSS 5.1 run in JDK 1.4 ??

We have a websphere server which runs in jdk 1.4

we need to access **jboss queue (configured in jboss 5.1)**. Inevitably we have to use jboss 5.1's client jars to access the queue

Am wondering (rather worrying) whether jboss 5.1 jar files will run in my system ; as my system has JDK 1.4

Requesting your inputs and suggestions

Comment: This should be answered on JBoss 5.1 documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I looked at the same and it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following site:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProjectJDKVersionRequirements

You need at least the JDK 1.5 for run Jboss 5.1.

So I think you have the following options:

- Since the jdk are backward compatibles (theorically) you can try to update your jdk from 1.4 to 1.5 (but you will need test your applications beacause some APIs can be deprecated or not fully compatibles)
- Other option is that you write a WebService i.e. with JAX-RPC on front of your JBoss an comsume it from your WebSphere application

Comment: Yes you are right !! Documentation also says the same. Thanks